# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input - always one less than model requires

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I get the following error trying to get predictions out of a gradient boosting model in sklearn.

ValueError: ('Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 24 and input n_features is 25 ', 'occurred at index 0')

My code looks something like this:

```
varcols=pickle.load(open("mycolumns","rb"))
model_use=pickle.load(open("my_model","rb"))
df['predictions']=df.apply(lambda x: 
model_use.predict(x[varcols].values[None])[0], axis=1).astype(int)
```

if I do something like this

```
tst=df[varcols]
len(tst.columns)
```

I get an output of 25. I don't have any null or missing values; everything is a float or an int.

Why am I getting this error? How do I assure my model that it in fact has 25 features to assess?

Comment: did you read in the index as an additional column

Comment: Any why would you use `apply()` here? Why not simply do `df['predictions'] = model_use.predict(x[varcols].values)`?